# How to optionally include a parameter in a Puppet class instance

Tags: puppet

I'm trying to optionally include a parameter in a puppet class instance. If a value is provided, the parameter should be passed to the class, and if it's empty it shouldn't be.

This the code I have so far:

```
class vcs (

    $path,
    $ensure,
    $provider,
    $source = '',
    $revision = '',
    $user = ''

)

{
    vcsrepo { $path:
      ensure   => $ensure,
      provider => $provider,
      source => $source ? {
        '' => nil,
        default => $source
      }
    }   

}
```

I've tried to set the value of the `source` parameter to be `nil` in case it isn't set, but Puppet doesn't seem to understand neither `nil` nor `null`. (I get a `fatal: repository 'null' does not exist` error)

Basically, I want to be able to call the `vcs` class, with only the `path` and `ensure` parameters to be required and all the others to be optional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution was to use `undef` instead of `nil`/`null`.